# Eclipse CDT can't find opencv 2 header files

Tags: eclipse, opencv, build, macports, eclipse-cdt

I installed opencv 2.3.1 with macports and the newest Eclipse CDT. Now I'm trying to compile this code:

```
>     #include <iostream.h>
>     #include <cv.h> // or opencv.hpp, no difference
>     
>     int main(int argc, char **argv) {
>     
>     
>     }
```

I have done all the steps of http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html but the output of the compiler is:

```
> make all  Building file: ../main.cpp Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler g++
> -I/opt/local/include/opencv -I/opt/local/include/opencv2 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp" In file included from
> /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/iostream.h:31,
>                  from ../main.cpp:8: /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning:
> #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section
> 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ includes, or <iostream> instead of
> the deprecated header <iostream.h>. To disable this warning use
> -Wno-deprecated. In file included from ../main.cpp:9: /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:46:33: error:
> opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:47:33: error:
> opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:39: error:
> opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:49:39: error:
> opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:50:39: error:
> opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:51:35: error:
> opencv2/video/video.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:45: error:
> opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:53:43: error:
> opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:54:39: error:
> opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:55:29: error: opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:
> No such file or directory /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:56:39:
> error: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:57:39: error:
> opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
> /opt/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:58:39: error:
> opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp: No such file or directory make: ***
> [main.o] Error 1
> 
> **** Build Finished ****
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By including /opt/local/include as well as /opt/local/include/opencv it worked strangely enough..

Answer (score 2):

okay.. I have had a lot of trouble in this myself.

You need to look int the opencv folder structure that you installed for these header files yourself. Sometimes they're not in the place the install guide tells you they are.

In my computer for example, most of the header files I needed are in:

[INSTALL DIRECTORY]/include/opencv
[INSTALL DIRECTORY]/include/opencv2

but SOME were in:

[INSTALL DIRECTORY]/modules/core/include/opencv2
[INSTALL DIRECTORY]/modules/highgui/include/opencv2 etc

you need to find those include files. Then go to your IDE (eclipse). In eclopse there should be a setting for the "include directories"

Set your IDE to look for include files in the directories where you know the include files are.

Then make sure you add the libraries. Ask if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

The errors listed above shows that you have not specified the paths of include directories.first you search for the include directories in your installation folder.Generally they are in /home/usr/include/opencv and /home/usr/local/include/opencv

After locating these files you open project properties in Eclipse CDT. Select  GCC C++ compiler -- directories and add the include directories there. Select GCC C++ Linker option and give the library path generally it is /usr/local/lib
Specify the libraries in quotes too e.g. "cv" , "highgui" etc.This will complete the configuration. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: actually I had to specify the specific libraries (core, imgproc, etc. - without "")